# Browser specific bug in my Drag and Drop functionality

Tags: javascript, compatibility, drag-and-drop, browser-bugs

I have a problem with my drag and drop javascript code.
With chrome it works but when I use firefox or internet explorer there are some problems.

For instance, with IE div data set to NULL and with firefox, my webpage is redirecting.

Thanks for all.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fr4NgUs/h399T/

```
this.innerHTML = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

Comment: Please post your code here too